# Locked out of VNC Viewer as keyboard has changed

Tags: keyboard, vnc

I was using my VNC Viewer and whatever I did, the keyboard changed.

I then got locked out of my window as when I was researching how to change the keyboard my session timed out.

My password contains an @ and I can't tell which key represents that so I am locked out.

I do know that "shift+/" gives me "_" on this new layout.

Does anyone know what (Combination of) key(s) represent an "@"?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably German, in which case RightAlt(AltGr)+q gives @

Here for example is a list of keyboard layouts. Click on numbers to see pictures of the layouts.

http://ascii-table.com/keyboards.php